# printing on Solaris lp or lpr

Tags: solaris, printing

On Solaris 10 I have a question about printing. Does it matter whether we use the lp or lpr command? What is the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is from System V Unix, and the other is from BSD.  Otherwise, there is no difference - they keep both for backwards compatibility.  You'll probably find one supports options the other doesn't, so if you need the options, use that one.